# cannot connect to SSH, ip address issue?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I have a workstation in my office that is plugged into the LAN. When i do a 'ip a', i get an internal ip address 10.x.x.x

i checked https://whatismyipaddress.com/ and my external ip address was 155.69.x.x

i tried connecting to the workstation from home via SSH using either of these IP addresses and it did not work.

is there some settings that i need to modify?

Comment: did you do any mapping from 155.69.X.X:22 to 10.x.x.x:22 ? if no, there is no way you can connect.

Comment: The first obvious step would be communicating that need to the local helpdesk.

Comment: @Archemar how do i do that?

Comment: This is called NAT, and might be complex to explain in simple word, if you have a local IT ask them, if you are the local IT, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Comment: Also note that the answer from local IT might be "Working as designed: you are not supposed to be able to connect directly from random internet computers into secure office network." Typically some kind of a centrally managed VPN solution would be the minimum recommended practice; if the company is serious about its network security, it might only allow company-managed laptops to connect to such a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

**is there some settings that i need to modify?**

## Yes.

You need to modify the "port forwarding" settings on your office's router (possibly more than one) so that inbound port 22 is forwarded to internal IP 10.x.x.x .

The internal IP address (10.x.x.x) makes no sense for anyone outside your organization, i.e. is not reachable. That is why you can communicate your internal IP address safely - mine, now, is 192.168.5.122 - and why neither you, nor anyone else, can connect to that address.

What *does* make sense is your *external* address. That you can use. But that machine is not usually *your* workstation; it is the one providing connectivity to *all* (or most, or some of - you get my drift) your organization's workstations. That workstation has usually no SSH server. Even if it had, it wouldn't be *yours*.

So you need to instruct that machine to *forward* inbound SSH connections to your machine on the internal network (the router is on the internal network, so 10.x.x.x makes sense for it).

This modification may require you submit a request to your sysadmin - it's unlikely that you'd be allowed to run it on your own, since opening port forwardings is a huge security risk. At the very least you'll be required to use an uncommon SSH port (e.g. 17943) instead of the 22 everybody knows and routinely tries to brute force. Other policies and tricks might also enter into play. You might also be required to first SSH on a secured box, using a certificate for example, and *then* SSH from there to your workstation.